# Delete tag html on PHP

Tags: php

How to delete tag html on php

my data:

```
$a="<div style='color: blue;'>Hallo</div>
<div>yas!</div><img src='blabla/aa/img.png'> im fine
<span> yes</span> <a href='aaa.com'>link</a>";
```

How to delete all div and span

```
<div style='color: blue;'></div>, <div></div> and <span></span>
```

and not delete

```
<img src='blabla/aa/img.png'> and <a href='aaa.com'>link</a>
```

Please help me

Comment: You want only image tag? in your data?

Comment: use regular expressions to replace div tags with empty string

Comment: not only image, because, image and other tag not like div and span

Comment: Your sentences can't explain your goal.

Comment: this should really be done with `DOMDocument` (PHP's in build HTML parser). and then looped through to remove content.. parsing html with Regex always is a bad idea.. see this famous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/648350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$a="<div style='color: blue;'>Hallo</div>"
   ."<div>yas!</div><img src='blabla/aa/img.png'> im fine<span> yes</span>";

$clean_html = strip_tags($a, "<img><a>");
```

Comment: how to add <img> and <a href> ?

Comment: @RepbAdhyMusaad: The second parameter of `strip_tags` is called `allowable_tags` and there you can list all the tags you *want to include* in your output.

Comment: i think this will still leave the " im fine" text (as it's not contained within a tag) wont it?

Comment: @haxxxton: correct, it will remove the `<span>` tag but not it's contents. So for example `strip_tags("<span>hello</span>");` will just return `"hello"`.

Comment: @vstm, ok, sorry just re-read OP's question, i read it as only return the allowed tags and their data, not to just remove the HTML tags.. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you have a white list of element then you can use the `strip_tags()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php.

Another option is to use http://htmlpurifier.org

WhiteList

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.AllowedElements

Blacklist

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.ForbiddenElements

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence cant explain what is your goal. Have a look at this.

**substr** — Return part of a string

**Description**

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

**Parameters**

**string**

The input string. Must be one character or longer.

**start**

If start is non-negative, the returned string will start at the start'th position in string, counting from zero. For instance, in the string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at position 2 is 'c', and so forth.

If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.

If string is less than or equal to start characters long, FALSE will be returned.

**Examples**

Example - Basic substr() usage

```
<?php
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f

// Accessing single characters in a string
// can also be achieved using "square brackets"
$string = 'abcdef';
echo $string[0];                 // a
echo $string[3];                 // d
echo $string[strlen($string)-1]; // f

?>
```

Or

If you want to remove HTML tags and only allow some of them you can use strip_tags function like this

```
 $a="<div style='color: blue;'>Hallo</div>"."<div>yas!</div><img src='blabla/aa/img.png'> im fine<span> yes</span>";
```

$clean_html = strip_tags($a, "");

This will return the text you entered $text with no tags except 
 &  tags You can read more about [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this:

```
 <?php 
$a="<div style='color: blue;'>Hallo</div><div>yas!</div><img src='blabla/aa/img.png'> im fine<span>   yes</span>";
echo strip_tags($a,"<img><a>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$a="<div style='color: blue;'>Hallo</div>
<div>yas!</div><img src='blabla/aa/img.png'> im fine<span> yes</span>";

$find=[
    "/<div style='color: blue;'>.*.<\/div>/",
    "/<div>.*.<\/div>/",
    "/<span>.*.<\/span>/"
];

echo preg_replace($find,"",$a);
```